# Encountering Constructor not defined in test class

Tags: unit-test, batch, schedulebatch, constructor

I'm scheduling a batchable class that deletes records from a custom object. The test class for my scheduled class saves without errors. However, I'm getting a "Constructor not defined: [deleteEndpointLogs].()" error when saving the test class for the batchable class and am getting stumped on how to resolve it.

Here is the code for the batch class:

```
global class deleteEndpointLogs implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
   global final String Query;
   global deleteEndpointLogs(String q){
    Query=q;
}

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Endpoint_Log__c> scope){
    delete scope;
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}
```

}

And here is my test class:

```
@isTest 
public class deleteEndpointLogsTest 
{
    static testMethod void testMethod1() 
    {
        List<Endpoint_Log__c> logList= new List<Endpoint_Log__c>();
        for(Integer i=0 ;i <200;i++)
        {
            Endpoint_Log__c log = new Endpoint_Log__c();
            log.Resource_Name__c ='Test'+i;
            logList.add(log);
        }
        
        insert logList;
        
        Test.startTest();

            deleteEndpointLogs batch = new deleteEndpointLogs();
            DataBase.executeBatch(batch); 
            
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

The error is on line 18 of the test class. Any help with getting this resolved is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your batch class does not contain a no-argument constructor, which you call here:

```
        deleteEndpointLogs batch = new deleteEndpointLogs();
```

Your constructor requires an argument, a query string:

```
global deleteEndpointLogs(String q){
```

It looks like you'll want to pass a query like `SELECT Id FROM Endpoint_Log__c LIMIT 100`, which will allow you to write assertions to validate that your class is deleting exactly as much as you asked it to delete and leaving other records unaltered.

Comment: Thanks David, really appreciate the response. I added this to my test class (right after ```Test.stopTest();```  but still encountering the same error: 

```Endpoint_Log__c epl = [SELECT ID FROM Endpoint_Log__c WHERE CreatedDateapextesting__c < LAST_N_DAYS:7 AND 
Resource_name__c != 'OpportunityResource' AND 
Processed__c = FALSE LIMIT 100];
        System.assert(epl.Id != null);```

Is something off with my assertion?

Comment: Did you also fix the constructor call?

Comment: Ah, missed that important detail. Got it all sorted now. Thanks for your help!